# A basic midterm question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm confused about one of my midterm questions:

> The third and fifth powers of every real number whose square is irrational are also irrational.

The instructor claims this is true. He uses contrapositive method. He claims $x^3$ and $x^5$ are rational and and since division of two rational number is rational $x^5/x^3=x^2$ is rational. ($x$ not equals $0$).

But $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational and $\sqrt[3]{4}$ is also irrational but $2$ which is $\sqrt[3]{8}$ is rational. Am I making an obvious mistake or is his answer wrong?

Comment: Who claims that tis is true? Do you have an image, so that we can see it?

Comment: He uses contrapositive method. He claims x$^3$ and x$^5$ are rational and and since division of two rational number is rational x$^5$/x$^3$=x$^2$ is rational. (x not equals 0).

Comment: Your counter example is good, and also shows the invalid step in the offered analysis.  $~x^5~$ and $~x^2~$ are both irrational, but $~x^3~$ is not.

Comment: @ArdaYonet That's an argument that if $x^2$ is irrational, then $x^3$ **or** $x^5$  is irrational.

Comment: Guys, I appreciate the efforts to improve the quality of the question, but y'all are putting words into the asker's mouth (as well as the mouths of other users).  Please feel free to suggest changes, but refrain from editing the question in a way which seems to fundamentally alter what is being said or asked.

Comment: @Prem The close reason was "lack of context", not lack of clarity.  I don't think that anyone claimed that the question was particularly unclear, only that it failed to meet site standards.

Comment: @Prem "Why was it deemed ok to reopen?"  (1) Lack of *context*, not lack of content.  (2) The question was closed by a vote of four users.  It was left closed in review (twice) by four other users.  It was reopened by the vote of five *other* users.  This is what we call "a difference of opinion".

Comment: @Prem The point is that the people who voted to close the question are not the people who voted to reopen it.  You can speculate to your heart's desire about whether those people would have voted to reopen *your* version of the question, but that's all it is---speculation.   For what it is worth, I wouldn't have---I don't think that this question is broadly interesting, applicable, or generalizable enough to merit retention in the database; but I was outvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement would be that when $x^2$ is irrational at least one of $x^3$ and $x^5$ is irrational.  Your example shows that it is possible for $x^2$ to be irrational and $x^3$ to be rational.  $\sqrt[5]2$ is an example for $x^5$.  I would read the statement to be saying that both $x^3$ and $x^5$ are irrational and agree with you that it is false.